# Defining size of array using clSetKernelArg

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I'm trying to initialise an array of size `numBins` inside of an OpenCL kernel, but cannot figure out what the first parameter of my `clSetKernelArg` should be. I'm using the below code.

```
cl::Kernel kernel = cl::Kernel(program, "histogram");
kernel.setArg(0, dev_image_input);
kernel.setArg(1, (int)image_input.size());
kernel.setArg(2, histogramBuffer);
kernel.setArg(3, numBins);

clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, numBins * sizeof(int), NULL);
```

I'm getting the below error.

`no suitable conversion function from "cl::Kernel" to "cl_kernel" exists`

I understand that I'm giving it a kernel object of the wrong class, what should I be giving it?

Answer (score 0):

With `cpp_kernel.setArg(...)`, you can either

- Insert a `cl::Buffer cpp_buffer;` at `int position;`: `cpp_kernel.setArg(position, cpp_buffer);`
- Insert a constant, for example an `float constant;`, at `int position;`. There is 2 ways to do it:

  - `cpp_kernel.setArg(position, sizeof(float), (void*)&constant);`
  - `cpp_kernel.setArg(position, constant);`

With the C function `clSetKernelArg(...)`, the syntax with `cl_kernel c_kernel;` and `cl_buffer c_buffer;` objects is as follows:

- For `cl_buffer c_buffer;`: `clSetKernelArg(c_kernel, position, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&c_buffer);`
- For constants: `clSetKernelArg(c_kernel, position, sizeof(float), (void*)&constant);`

To put the C++ `cl::Kernel cpp_kernel;` or `cl::Buffer cpp_buffer;` in the C function `clSetKernelArg`, use the `()` operators: `clSetKernelArg(cpp_kernel(), position, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cpp_buffer());`. Background: The overloaded `()` operators return the `cl_kernel`/`cl_buffer` objects.

---

To not have to worry about the syntax and to eliminate all code overhead associated with the OpenCL setup, use this lightweight [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper) for C++. There you can create a Kernel in 1 line, for example:

```c
Kernel kernel(device, N, "kernel_opencl_c_name", buffer_A, buffer_B, 1.4f, buffer_C, constant);
```

Comment: But I can't pass my kernel into ```clSetKernelArg```, as it is of type ```cl::Kernel```, not ```cl_kernel```. How can I work around this?

Comment: To put the C++ `cl::Kernel kernel;` or `cl::Buffer buffer;` in the C function `clSetKernelArg`, use the `()` operators: `clSetKernelArg(kernel(), position, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&buffer());`. Background: The overloaded `()` operators return the `cl_kernel`/`cl_buffer` objects.